# Pasting cell entries into one cell and deleting empty cells

Tags: r, cell, paste

I have the following problem:
I have a table with many empty cells. But the first column does not contain empty cells. Like this:

```
structure(list(variable = c("variable", "Mean (M)", "Standard", 
"deviation", "(SD)", "1. Challenge"), M = c("M", "", "", "", 
"", "3.06"), SD = c("SD", "", "", "", "", "1.08"), X1 = c("1", 
"3.03", "1.09", "", "", ""), X2 = c("2", "2.19", "1.07", "", 
"", "â\210’0.06"), X3 = c("3", "1.93", "1.10", "", "", "0.52***"
), X4 = c("4", "1.86", "1.04", "", "", "â\210’0.14*")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

[How it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxz6h.png)

Now I would like to paste the entries of the two cells under Standard (= "deviation" and "(SD)") into on cell and delete these rows containing only empty cells. So the output should look like this:

```
structure(list(variable = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1. Challenge", 
"Mean (M)", "Standard deviation SD", "variable"), class = "factor"), 
    M = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "3.06", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    SD = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "1.08", "SD"
    ), class = "factor"), `1` = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "1", "1.09", "3.03"), class = "factor"), `2` = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 4L), .Label = c("1.07", "2", "2.19", "â\210’0.06"), class = "factor"), 
    `3` = structure(3:1, .Label = c("0.52***", "1.10", "1.93", 
    "3"), class = "factor"), `4` = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1.04", 
    "1.86", "4", "â\210’0.14*"), class = "factor")), row.names = 2:4, class = "data.frame")
```

[How I would like it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0N1o.png)

Can you help? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can drop the columns missing data, and then just manually rename that column. `df <- tidyr::drop_na(df, -variable); df[2,1] <- "Standard deviation SD"`.

Comment: But this does not help as the problem is not NA, but blank cells! I tried this: ```no_blank_Table <-Tab[!(Tab$SD==""), ]``` but then I lose the first few rows as well. I want to delete the rows that contain ONLY blank cells (disregarding the first column). Any idea?

Comment: You can convert all blank values to NA fairly easily using dplyr: `df <- mutate_all(df, ~ na_if(., ''))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a grouping column based on the occurrence of blanks (`""`) in all the columns except the first and then `paste` the elements of each of the columns when the number of rows are greater than 1 and get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(grp = cumsum(rowSums(.[-1] == "") != ncol(.)-1))  %>%  
    mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(n() > 1) str_c(., collapse=" ") else .) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    select(-grp) %>% 
    distinct
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! I don't know whether this is needed, but I simplified it a bit: <br/> `Table2 %>% 
    group_by(grp = cumsum(rowSums(.[-1] == "") != ncol(.)-1))  %>%  
    mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(n() > 1) str_c(., collapse=" ") else .) %>% 
  unique(.) %>% 
  .[-1, -10]`

Comment: @Anne-KathrinKleine  Thank you.  The `type.convert` is useed to change the type of each column (if needed) and `unique` is a base R similar to `distinct` from `dplyr`